# SwiftUI Binding変数のプレビューでの表示について

Tags: swift, swiftui

Date型のBinding変数をプレビューで記載する方法がわかりません。
以下のようなコードがあり、Binding変数の例として、4/4/2020を入れて、プレビュー表示させたいのですが、どのようにプレビューに記載すれば良いでしょうか。
ご教授のほど、よろしくお願い致します。

````
struct ConfirmView: View{
    @Binding var name:String
    @Binding var gender:String
    @Binding var birthDate:Date
    @Binding var mail:String
    @Binding var password:String
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{

            Text("aa")
        }
    }
}

struct ConfirmView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConfirmView(name: .constant("hiroshi"), gender: .constant("男"), birthDate: Date(4/4/2020), mail: .constant("abc.com"), password: .constant("12345"))
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`constant(_:)`メソッド](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3134578-constant)をご存知なのであれば、値として`4/4/2020`を表す`Date`型の式を指定することだけです。

(とは言え、あまり便利メソッドのないAppleのDate型では、そこが面倒なのですが。ところで`4/4/2020`と言うのはアメリカ式の`月/日/年`でしょうか、ヨーロッパ式の`日/月/年`でしょうか?以下の回答はAppleの所在地に合わせ、アメリカ式です。)

```
struct ConfirmView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let birthDate: Date = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_us_POSIX")
        //df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        return df.date(from: "4/4/2020")!
    }()
    static var previews: some View {
        ConfirmView(name: .constant("hiroshi"), gender: .constant("男"), birthDate: .constant(birthDate), mail: .constant("abc.com"), password: .constant("12345"))
    }
}
```

`Date`型で(時刻を除く)日付だけを表すと言うのは結構面倒な点があれこれ出てきます。使い方によっては、コメントアウトしてあるタイムゾーンの設定をコードインしてもらった方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: この度は、丁寧にご指導いただき、ありがとうございました。問題は解決し、大変参考になりました。